# Can I extend WebSphere Liberty buildpack?

Tags: websphere-liberty, ibm-cloud

I am looking for extending WebSphere Liberty buildpack included in Bluemix with some third party libraries from our application architecture, so the size of EAR file will decrease a lot and cf push command will be more fast and agile. Is it possible?

I know there is a WebSphere Liberty buildpack open sourced at Cloudfoundry.org but as far as I know, it is not so powerful like the one included in Bluemix and we would loose some interesting features.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Liberty buildpack you find on GitHub should be pretty similar to the one Bluemix uses especially in terms of features.  Beta features are included and auto-configuration should work so in theory if you do `cf push appName -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack.git -p myapp.war` it should work the same way if you did `cf push appName -p myapp.war`.

If you want to modify the buildpack you can fork it and add the jars you want although I am unsure on the process for adding the jars.  Maybe someone else can add an answer that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about adding a custom shared library, this means some JARs in user directory plus a config inside server.xml file.

Comment: It's worth noting that auto-configuration in the open-source buildpack is for MySQL, PostgreSQL, and MongoDB, while the buildpack Bluemix uses supports auto-configuration for other Bluemix services as well.

Comment: That's the reason I was looking for extending Bluemix one @opiethehokie

Answer (score 3):

You can find an alternative buildpack for Websphere Liberty [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack.git). As you will notice, it is actually a CloudFoundry buildpack -- normally all of them will work in Bluemix. To use it, add a `buildpack:` line to your `manifest.yml` or a `-b` option to `cf` command line tool.

There is not much detail in your question as to what libraries or modifications you need, but this buildpack is in github and you can freely fork it and modify it. The buildpack prepares the runtime, and you should be able to add your own downloads in some hooks and replicate the directory structure you must be using locally. It is also very well documented, so you should find your way through the configurations if you are doing anything non-standard.

You are welcome to share your own new buildpack too!

Comment: Libraries I need to add are Spring, Hibernate, custom extensions, etc... needed by our apps. It would be nice if they can be part of the runtime so EAR files will be really smaller. I was aware of that Open Source buildpack but my question was related to Bluemix one because as far as I know Bluemix one is more powerful with binding detection, beta features included, etc...

Comment: I understand. I referred to CloudFoundry , as Bluemix is based on CloudFoundry, and all references (and builldpacks) you will find for CloudFoundry will usually work on Bluemix as well. Some buildpacks are customized for Bluemix and have specific Bluemix repositories, the many of them including Java's buildpack will work out of the box in Bluemix.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be more efficient during the development cycle where you constantly push changes, you can try the 'development mode' support in the Bluemix Liberty buildpack. This allows you to push incremental file changes without even restarting the Liberty server (not to mention the whole application container, aka no cf push). See the doc here: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/eclipsetools/eclipsetools.html#incrementalpublish.  You can also do remote debugging with development mode.

Comment: I think the correct URL is this one. https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#manageapps/eclipsetools/eclipsetools.html#incrementalpublish

Comment: Can this incremental push be driven from the command line? I mostly rely on maven and `cf`

Comment: Yes, install this CF CLI plugin: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/plugins/dev_mode/index.html

Answer (score 1):

To customize a Liberty server in Bluemix, you can also use the `server package` command of a local Liberty server, and then `cf push` the generated zip.

See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/msardana/entry/developing_with_bluemix_customizing_the_liberty_build_pack_to_add_your_configurations for details

That, of course, defeats your goal of smaller deployment times, but I wanted to add the possibility for completeness and to prevent someone from forking the buildpack without needing it.